# How to display and sort images from sd card like images displayed in google photos app

Tags: android, date, gallery

I have a local `database` which has paths for all images and it's all stored in a single folder on `sdcard`. Help me to sort & display all those images like today's photos comes first under the title **Today**, then **Yesterday**, **Last Week** and so on. Refer the [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBHel.jpg) to have more clarity on this question

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: i need a idea how to create that page, i haven't started coding yet.

Comment: You should use the section listview ..there are lots of example avilable...let try them..If you get any coding relating problem than paste your code here

Answer (score 0):

you can try to learn it from following free source code on github

https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery

https://github.com/dibakarece/OwnGalleryView

Answer (score 0):

You can see the file last modified time by using `file.lastModified()` this will return last modified time. Then you can put your segregation logic based this time.